# jQuery hover function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm just trying to do a simple jquery effect but am having issues with the second part of the `.hover` function. Here's the code:

```
<div id="toprightboxes">
<ul>
    <li><div id="login"><img src="img/login.png"/></div></li>
    <li>info</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $("#login").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).replaceWith('<div id="login"><img src="img/loginhighlight.png"/></div>');
        },
        function () {
            $(this).replaceWith('<div id="login"><img src="img/loginhighlight.png"/></div>');
        }
    );
</script>
```

The first part of the hover works and the highlight image shows up but when I move off of the image nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ehm, its the same IMAGE you replace back...

Secondly why use jQuery for such a hover effect? You can easily do this with a:hover {} and pure CSS.

Comment: Sometimes I amaze myself with my smart typing abilities. Also I had thought that the pseudo class hover had some issues with IE7 but upon exploring more it doesn't look like it so thanks for that also

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo — your event for `mouseleave` is the same as the one for `mouseenter`. Is this what you meant?

```
<div id="toprightboxes">
<ul>
    <li><div id="login"><img src="img/login.png"/></div></li>
    <li>info</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $("#login").hover(
        function () {
        $(this).replaceWith('<div id="login"><img src="img/loginhighlight.png"/></div>');
        },
        function () {
        $(this).replaceWith('<div id="login"><img src="img/login.png"/></div>');
                }
    );
</script>
```

If all you're doing is changing the image, though, you might want to consider using CSS instead.